# I am getting null value from ascx file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, uploadify, ashx

I am getting null value from Plaka .How can I solve this problem.pages created dynamically inside the ascx file .

javascript part:

```
   var myFunction = function()
     {
                            Vp=  #{txtPlaka}.getValue();
           $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify('upload','*');
     };



    $(document).ready(function () {

          var Vp ="";
          $('#btnMusteriEkle').click(myFunction);

        $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify({
            'uploader': 'Upload.ashx',
            'swf': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': 'Upload.ashx',
            'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
            'folder': 'upload',
            'multi': true,
            'method': 'post',
            'buttonText': 'RESIM SEC',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg',
            'auto': false,
            'formData': { 'id': 'id', 'Plaka': Vp, 'Foo':'foooo'},
            onAllComplete: function (event, data) {

            }

        });

    });


</script>
```

upload.ashx file

/// I am getting null value here(pwd5).pwd1 and pwd2 is okey,
    ///I can catch them values

```
            string pwd5 = context.Request.Form["Plaka"]; 
            string pwd1 = context.Request.Form["Id"];
            string pwd2 = context.Request.Form["Foo"];
```

and here is the markup syntax

```
<ext:TextField ID="txtPlaka" runat="server" FieldLabel="Plaka" Flex="1" AllowBlank="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </ext:TextField>


 <ext:Button runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="btnMusteriEkle" Text="Yeni müşteri ekle">
          <Listeners>
           <Click Handler="
          $('#FileUpload1').uploadify('upload','*'))">  
          </Click>
           </Listeners>
    </ext:Button>
```

Here is the my logic I followed: first inside the ready function created var Vp="";later bind the function called myFunction, later, run the uplodify function.when the user clicked the button, this binding already defined ($('#btnMusteriEkle').click(myFunction);), directly run the myFunction and asigned Vp value as #{txtPlaka}.getValue();and run uplodify() function, those value(Vp), should pass the uploadify function but so far, nope doesn't work.

Comment: What's the 4th line supposed to do?

Comment: What i see here is: You created the variable Vp, add a listener to it, and then straightly execute the uploadify function, before Vp changes it's value.

Comment: 4th ?? wheere exactlly it is

Comment: how can I fisrt change Vp and later run the uplodify function this one ( $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify('upload','*');)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna take a wild guess here, i don't know much about ascx files.

Question: Is this the part you use to upload?

```
    $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify({
    'uploader': 'Upload.ashx',
    'swf': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script': 'Upload.ashx',
    'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
    'folder': 'upload',
    'multi': true,
    'method': 'post',
    'buttonText': 'RESIM SEC',
    'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg',
    'auto': false,
    'formData': { 'id': 'id', 'Plaka': Vp, 'Foo':'foooo'},
    onAllComplete: function (event, data) {
```

Meanwhile try this:

```
var upload;
var myFunction = function()
 {
       Vp=  {txtPlaka}.getValue();
       upload()
 };



$(document).ready(function () {

    var Vp ="";
    $('#btnMusteriEkle').click(myFunction);

    upload = function(){
        $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify({
        'uploader': 'Upload.ashx',
        'swf': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': 'Upload.ashx',
        'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
        'folder': 'upload',
        'multi': true,
        'method': 'post',
        'buttonText': 'RESIM SEC',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg',
        'auto': false,
        'formData': { 'id': 'id', 'Plaka': Vp, 'Foo':'foooo'},
        onAllComplete: function (event, data) {

        }

    });
  }

});
```

Comment: but where is the this part.$("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify('upload','*'); without this part never loading happen.

Comment: Updated, check my question there.

Comment: when loading first time yes u are right I am calling this.which is a represnt flash button.but wanna load bulky ,I need this one to fire event.$("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify('upload','*');

Comment: Because i think the code in `ready()` function, `upload()` function in my answer, is executing the script straight away.

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but what happen if you run my script?