# Changing global variable value inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my simple scenario. I have a variable defined inside the `ready()` function which assigns the first value.

I also have a function outside `ready()`. What I want to do is to use the changed variable inside my new function.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    // I wanna change Vp value here and wanna 
    // use this function with the new value        
    Vp = "new value";

    myFunction2 (); 
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    var Vp = "first value asign";
    $('#btnAddCustomer').click(myFunction);

    var myFunction2 = function() {
        // I will use Vp variable here with new value
    };
});
```

Comment: [JSFiddled.](http://jsfiddle.net/XGGvv/2)

Comment: Why don't you move `myFunction()` inside the same `ready` scope?

Comment: $('#btnAddCustomer').click(myFunction); here called .whenever clint click the button it fires

Comment: why not attach not variable to window or document?

Comment: can u give me a sample how I can do this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Discard the `var` statement. It assigned the value to a new local variable, instead of the global variable.

Here:

```
var Vp = "first assigned value"
var myFunction2;

var myFunction = function() {
    // I wanna change Vp value here and wanna use this function with the new value        

    Vp =  "new value"
    myFunction2(); 

    };

$(document).ready(function () {

    Vp = "first value asign";

    $('#btnAddCustomer').click(myFunction);

    myFunction2 = function() {

    alert(Vp)

    };

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XGGvv/10/

NOW THAT WORKS.

A nice reading on JS variable scopes: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: You should still declare the variable, but in the global scope.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't complete. Check it now.

Comment: nope it doent work your soliton ,stilll get the Vp = "first value asign" value inside the ready function but need the new value

Comment: Do you declare Vp on myfunction2?

Comment: inside the myFunction  function,need to change Vp and pass this new value to the function of myFunction2

Comment: tried your solution but still get the  var Vp = "first value asign"; inside the function2

Comment: I tried the code, and it works fine. Except that there's an error, myfunction2 is undefined. Try my second solution.

Comment: emmm nope it is not possiable in my senario to pass it as argument

Comment: pls give me sample without using passing parameter from function to function

Comment: dear friend akkid .I tryed your soliton to my secanrio but doent work .I see that your logic is correct and working.here is the my secario.if u take a look at it and say your opinoun,I am glad to .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197103/i-am-getting-null-value-from-ascx-file